# How to compute the Clebsch Gordan-coefficients for spin-angular momentum coupling of Hydrogen?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, hydrogen

Consider a hydrogen atom with Hamiltonian $H$, angular momentum $L$ and spin operator $S$ and total angular momentum $J:= L+S$. Since $H,L^2, J^2$ and $J_z$ all commute with each other, we can find a joint eigenbasis $\{|n,l,j,m_j\rangle : 0\le l,j\le n-1\,, m_j=-j,\ldots,j\}$ with canonical quantum numbers. My lecture notes now claim that

$$|n,l,j=l\pm1/2,m_j\rangle=A_{\pm}|n,l,m_j-1/2\rangle\otimes|+\rangle + B_{\pm}|n,l,m_j+1/2\rangle\otimes|-\rangle$$ for $A_{\pm},B_{\pm}\in\mathbb{C}$ the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.

**Question:** How does one obtain this? As far as I understand, we have $$|n,l,j,m_j\rangle=\sum_{m_l=-l}^{l}c_{m_l,+}|n,l,m_l\rangle\otimes|+\rangle + \sum_{m_l=-l}^{l}c_{m_l,-}|n,l,m_l\rangle\otimes|-\rangle$$ so how does one introduce the quantum number $m_j$ here and show that only two summands are non-zero? I know that for the "classical" CG coefficients of the hydrogen atom, we have that the quantum number of $J_z$ must be the sum of the $m_j$. Can I maybe apply that here? Furthermore, the classical CG formalism does not use the quantum numbers $n$ and $l$ (or at least assumes that $l$ is fixed) so even the expansion $$|n,l,j,m_j\rangle=\sum_{m_l=-l}^{l}c_{m_l,+}|n,l,m_l\rangle\otimes|+\rangle + \sum_{m_l=-l}^{l}c_{m_l,-}|n,l,m_l\rangle\otimes|-\rangle$$ is a mere guess of mine.

Comment: Yes, this conservation law holds whenever you couple angular momentum operators. The formalism is agnostic to which ones are "orbital" and which ones are "spin".

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thanks for the comment but even then I only come as far as $|n,l,j,m_j\rangle=\sum_{m_l=-l}^{l}c_{m_l,+}|n,l,m_l\rangle\otimes|+\rangle + \sum_{m_l=-l}^{l}c_{m_l,-}|n,l,m_l\rangle\otimes|-\rangle$, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me go back to the beginning and state the question more clearly. We have a quantum system in which there are two angular momenta $\vec L$ and $\vec S$ that are coupled, so that $\vec J = \vec L + \vec S$ is conserved.  Then, $J^2$, $L^2$, $S^2$ mutually commute and can be used as good quantum numbers.  In the Hydrogen atom example, $S = 1/2$.  This makes the problem much simpler, and so I will work with this example, although the method can be generalized to any $S$.

In the following, I will assume that $L$ and $S$ are fixed and I will not write $L$ and $S$ explicitly.  The value of $J$ will depend on the relative orientation of $\vec L$ and $\vec S$.  There are two possibilities: $J = L+1/2$ and $J = L - 1/2$.

There are two ways to label the states of the system.  We can use the labels of total angular momentum  $J, m_j$ or we can use the labels of the z angular momentum for $L$ and $S$,  $m_\ell, m_s$. Since $J$ is the sum of $L$ and $S$, $m_j = m_\ell + m_s$. Since $S = 1/2$, $m_s = \pm 1/2$.

The total Hilbert space has dimension  $2 (2 L + 1)$.  But this is divided into 2-dimensional subspaces that do not mix with one another.   A typical subspace contains the states
$$   | J = L+{1\over 2},  m_j\rangle   \qquad   | J = L - {1\over 2}, m_j\rangle $$
or, in the $m_\ell, m_s$ basis,
$$    | m_j-{1\over 2}, +{1\over 2}\rangle   \qquad   | m_j + {1\over 2}, -{1\over 2}\rangle \ . $$
These pairs of states give two different orthogonal bases for the same Hilbert space.  They are related by a unitary transformation. The Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are **defined** to be the elements of this $2\times 2$ unitary matrix. Clebsch-Gordan coefficients can be written $c_{m_j,+}$, etc., as in the question, but it is much more transparent to write them as explicitly indicating this change of basis,
$$  \langle L S m_\ell m_s|LS J m_j\rangle \quad \mbox{or, simply} \quad \langle m_\ell m_s|J m_j\rangle \ . $$
In the standard conventions, Clebsch-Gordon coefficients are real-valued.  Then the first equation of the question can be rewritten
$$  | J m_j> = \langle (m_j-{1\over 2}) (+{1\over 2})|J m_j\rangle \ |(m_j-{1\over 2})(+{1\over 2})\rangle \\ +  \langle (m_j+{1\over 2}) (-{1\over 2})|J m_j\rangle \ |(m_j+{1\over 2}) (-{1\over 2})\rangle \ , $$
which is much more transparent.

Up to this point, everything is formalism.  But we are now in a good position to answer the question of how to compute the Clebsh-Gordan coefficients.  The arguments below can be found in many textbooks on quantum mechanics.  I recommend especially Gordon Baym's "Lectures on Quantum Mechanics", which has a whole chapter (Chapter 15) devoted to the addition of angular momenta.

The key is that, while most of the subspaces are 2-dimensional, there are two special subspaces that are 1-dimensional.  There is only one state with $m_j = J+1/2$,
$$   | J = (L+{1\over 2}), m_j = (L+{1\over 2}) \rangle  =   | L, (+{1\over 2})\rangle \ ,$$
and there is only one state with $m_j = -L- 1/2$,
$$   | J= (L+{1\over 2}), m_j = -(L+{1\over 2})\rangle  =  \pm | (-L), (-{1\over 2})\rangle \ ,$$
Then
$$ \langle (L+{1\over 2})(L+{1\over 2}) | L(+1/2)\rangle = 1 \qquad 
  \langle (-L-{1\over 2}), (-L-{1\over 2}) | (-L)(-1/2)\rangle  = \pm 1  $$
(The relative sign $\pm$ has to be worked out by the process given below.)

Taking the first equation here as a starting point, we apply the operator $J^- = (J^x - i J^y)$.  $J^-$ commutes with $J^2$, so the action of this operator preserves $J$.  On a state $|Jm\rangle$, it can be shown
$$   J^- \ |jm\rangle = [ j(j+1) - m(m-1)]^{1/2} | j (m-1)\rangle
 \ . $$
This equation appears in the proof of the quantization of angle momentum that can be found in any quantum mechanics text.  But here we will use it as a tool.  Apply $J^-$ to $|(L+{1\over 2})(L+{1\over 2})\rangle$,
$$   J^- |(L+{1\over 2})(L+{1\over 2})\rangle = \sqrt{2L+1} |(L+{1\over 2})(L-{1\over 2})\rangle\ . $$
Now write $J^- = L^- + S^-$ and apply this to $| L, (+{1\over 2})\rangle$,
$$  J^- | L, (+{1\over 2})\rangle = \sqrt{2L}\cdot | (L-1), (+ {1\over 2})\rangle + 1 \cdot | L, (-{1\over 2})\rangle $$
Now we have found that
$$  \sqrt{2L+1} |(L+{1\over 2})(L-{1\over 2})\rangle =  \sqrt{2L}\cdot | (L-1), (+ {1\over 2})\rangle + 1 \cdot | L, (-{1\over 2})\rangle $$
and so we can identify
$$  \langle (L-1)(+{1\over 2})| (L+{1\over 2}) (L-{1\over 2})\rangle  =\sqrt{{2L\over 2L+1}}  \qquad  \langle L(-{1\over 2})| (L+{1\over 2})(L -{1\over 2})\rangle  =\sqrt{{1\over 2L+1} }\ . $$

There is only one state in the 2-dimensional subspace that is orthogonal to
$|(L+1/2)(L-1/2)\rangle$.  That is the state with $J = L-1/2$ and $m_j = L-1/2$.  Then that state must be the one orthogonal to the above,
$$   |(L-{1\over 2})(L-{1\over 2})\rangle =  - \sqrt{{1\over 2L+1}}\cdot | (L-1), (+ {1\over 2})\rangle + \sqrt{{2L\over 2L+1}} \cdot | L, (-{1\over 2})\rangle $$
up to an overall sign, which can only be fixed by convention.
Then we can identify
$$  \langle (L-1)(+{1\over 2})| (L+{1\over 2}) (L-{1\over 2})\rangle  = - \sqrt{{1\over 2L+1}}  \qquad  \langle L(-{1\over 2})| (L+{1\over 2})(L -{1\over 2})\rangle  =\sqrt{{2L\over 2L+1}}\ . $$

We can continue similarly to the states with $m_j = L-3/2$ by applying $J^-$ one more time.  In a similar way, we can compute all of the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients needed for this problem.

It is a nice exercise to carry out this process explicitly for a fixed value of $L$, for example, $L=1$, and compare your results to those in a reference table.  A nice table can be found in Griffiths' Quantum Mechanics book, Table 4.8, or at the original source:
https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/reviews/rpp2020-rev-clebsch-gordan-coefs.pdf  .

Answer (score 1):

$n$ does not enter in angular momentum coupling as the operators $\hat L_x, \hat L_\pm$ do not change $n$.  Thus the $n$’s are those of the original states you want to couple, and the CG’s are the “standard ones” as they do not depend on $n$’s.

Finally note that since $J_z=L_z+S_z$, indeed $m_j=m_\ell+ m_s$ else the CG is $0$.  Any half-decent QM text will have this, although I recommend

> Khersonskii, V.K., Moskalev, A.N. and Varshalovich, D.A., 1988. Quantum Theory of Angular Momemtum. World Scientific.

as *the* authoritative source of tables and properties of everything angular momentum.  AFAIK, there no English e-version available at this time (pity!), although there is a GoogleBook substitute partially available.